How to select dSYM / app in Xcode Instruments for symbolication
I'm trying to instrument my iPhone app via Xcode's Instruments tool. Problem is, Instruments isn't symbolicating correctly, so I can't tell which lines of code are causing app hangs / troubles.
Per some related posts on Stack Overflow and the internet in general, I've tried adding a dSYM search path in Instruments by going to Instruments > Settings > Symbols. However, when I go to select what appears to be my app (UnitConversions.app), it's grayed out an not selectable (see screenshot below).
My Xcode project build settings are configured so that Debug Information Format equals DWARF with dSYM File. At this point, I'm out of ideas as to how I can add the proper dSYM to Instruments and get it to be able to symbolicate properly.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Update (05/23/2024): I'm attaching a screenshot of the sheet that shows on my version of Instruments (15.3) when I select File > Symbols (for comparison purposes). It does not seem to contain the "Executables" or "Incomplete" tabs that appear in many examples online (or Swift Dev Journal's answer below).


Xcode projects are set up to use dSYM files for Release builds, not Debug builds. Debug builds place the debugging symbols in the executable instead of a separate dSYM file. In your screenshot you are showing a Debug version of your app, which would explain why there's no dSYM file for you to select.
The way to locate a dSYM file to use with Instruments is to choose File > Symbols in Instruments. A sheet like the following opens:

Select your app from the list on the left. Click the Locate button to find the dSYM file.
The Symbols menu item may be disabled until you finish a trace session.

Thanks for your answer. The distinction between Debug and Release builds is very helpful. I know you can change the Build Options and make it so that Debug builds generate dSYM files if you want. I've done that (and tried a Release build as well). The dSYM generates in both cases. However, if I choose File > Symbols, my sheet looks different from yours (I added a screenshot to my original question). It looks as though my app is symbolicated, but I still can't get symbols to show. Any other ideas? Thanks.

I saw in your screenshot that your app was built for the Simulator. Do you get debugging symbols if your profile your app on a device? Are you able to locate a dSYM file  when profiling on a device?

Sorry for the delay. Yes, when I run from xcode with a physical device, the dSYM locates and I can see all the stack traces / call logs. Still not entirely sure why the simulator doesn't produce the same effect but, for now, it solves the issue. So, thanks!
